# fancybox not working in div tag

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, typeerror

I am facing one problem with fancybox loading.
I have following page layout:
[image]

I have written code for including `jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.js` and `jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css` in `browse.php` file as well as CSS for fancybox (suggest me if I have included in wrong file instead of `explorer.php`)

```
$(".view_details").fancybox( {
                    'overlayOpacity' : 0.1,
                    'showCloseButton' : true,
                    'frameHeight' : 250,
                    'frameWidth' : 300,
                    'hideOnContentClick':false,
                    'centerOnScroll' : false
                });
```

, Now `browse.php` is loaded each time when user click on link in `DIV 1` pane.

In `browse.php` I am calling fancybox on a link,

```
<a class="view_details" href="file.php?par=1" >View Details </a>
```

But Its not working, sometime its open at very first time and then onwards showing error that `TypeError: loading is undefined`.
Please help me in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing

First I realize that `DIV` tag bind with the parent container (Like parent page which contains `DIV` tag), so sometime `JavaScript` and `CSS` dont bind with `DOM` component.

Second , I have relace `DIV` with `IFRAME` and now its working good as per desire. The reason I have noticed that `IFRAME` treat its inner source as different page and load whole page as another `window object` like we do with `window.open()`. So `Javascript` and `CSS` binds perfectly in it.

I have replace:

```
<div id="file_list" style="float: left;width: 80%;overflow: auto"></div>
```

with

```
<iframe id="doc_list" name="doc_list" style="height: 500px;width: 98%;border: 0px"></iframe>
```

And set desire page as `SRC` to `IFRAME` while clicking on folder in left `DIV 1 pane`.

```
document.getElementById("doc_list").src = "desire_page.php";
```

Cheers!